# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a una función dentro de otra importandola desde otro módulo?

Tags: python-3.x, funciones, entrada

Estoy haciendo un programa en python que me permita calcular el área de un polígono a partir de las coordenadas de este en el plano y para ello cuento con tres módulos: entrada.py (para ingresar el número de lados del polígono y las coordenadas de los vértices), cálculos.py (para obtener el área del polígono) y salida.py (para mostrar en pantalla los pares de coordenadas y el área del polígono con un mensaje).

En el módulo cálculos.py tengo lo siguiente:

```
#cálculos.py

from salida import vértices

def área_polígono():
  n=len(vértices)
  área=0.0

  for i in range(n):
    j=(i+1)%n

    área+=vértices[i][0]*vértices[j][1]
    área-=vértices[j][0]*vértices[i][1]

  global área_polígono
  área_polígono=0.5*abs(área)

  return (área_polígono)
```

En el módulo salida.py tengo lo siguiente:

```
#salida.py

from entrada import x,y

def pares():
  """ Esta función permite mostrar los pares ordenados de coordenadas (xi,yi) de cada uno de los vértices del polígono. """

  global vértices
  vértices=list(zip(x,y))

  return(f"Pares= {vértices}")

print(pares())


from cálculos import área_polígono

def área_del_polígono():
  """ Esta función permite mostrar el valor del área del polígono. """

  return (f"El área del polígono es: {área_polígono} U^2" )

print(área_del_polígono())
```

Al correr el programa me sale lo siguiente:

```
El área del polígono es: <function área_polígono at 0x7fcf4f7a69d0> U^2
```

¿Qué debo hacer para que me salga el valor del área del polígono?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo en el código no estas ejecutando en sí la función del área_polígono. Para ejecutar una función requieren los paréntesis **()** 
Por ejemplo

```
def funcion():
    global funcion
    funcion = 3.14
    return funcion


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f'Mi valor es : {funcion}')
```

Respuesta : `Mi valor es : <function funcion at 0x000002CC5960C268>`

Ahora llamando a la función para que se ejecute con **()**

```
def funcion():
    global funcion
    funcion = 3.14
    return funcion


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f'Mi valor es : {funcion()}')


respuesta: Mi valor es : 3.14
```

Como se puede apreciar ahora si estoy llamando a ejecutarse la función mediante el uso de paréntesis 
Espero que mi respuesta te ayude :)

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!